# Is nonlocality more fundamental to quantum theory than superpositions?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, non-locality

What is more fundamental to quantum mechanics: nonlocality or superpositions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lack of locality is just as much a feature of Quantum Mechanics as it is of Classical Mechanics. To wit, Newton's law of gravitation is very directly a law that has the phenomenon of action-at-a-distance built-in. You sneeze and it has an instantaneous gravitational impact on the Andromeda galaxy, in Newton's theory.

Non-locality is prohibited by the principles of Relativity--not by any inherent feature of Classical Mechanics per se. Thus, when we combine the principles of Relativity with Classical Mechanics, we prohibit non-local theories.

Similarly, when we combine principles of Relativity with Quantum Mechanics, we do prohibit non-local theories. In particular, it is ensured that the Lagrangian (density) is always local and observables at spacelike separated points commute with each other.